# Passing two values as string to same activity returns one value null

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

This is my code to display two values: Recommended insulin dose and administered insulin dose. The two value is passed to another activity.

I have used two intent to pass two values to another activity(NewActivity).

The problem is as two intents are used only one value is displayed. The output is displayed as:

> Recommended insulin dosage:null, Administered insulin dosage:10 (correct value of the calculation).

If the startActivity(intent) is removed from the button.setOnClickListener the output is displayed as:

> Recommended insulin dosage:23 (correct value), Administered insulin dosage:null.

One of the value is becoming null. How to get two values displayed?

I tried declaring the string as public also

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Button button;
private Button button2;
private EditText editText;
private EditText editText2;
private EditText editText4;
public static String myid;
public static String insulin;
private Spinner dynamicSpinner;
private ProgressDialog loading;





   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String carbval=intent.getStringExtra("carbval");

    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText2.setText(carbval);
    dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    editText4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);




   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String carbohydrate = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
            String dailydose = editText4.getText().toString().trim();
            int cc = Integer.parseInt(carbohydrate);
            int dd = Integer.parseInt(dailydose);
            int goc = 450 / dd;
            int ab = cc / goc;
            myid = Integer.toString(ab);
            Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("ids",myid);
            startActivity(intent1);


        }
    });




Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.brew_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    staticAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

    Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);

    String[] items = new String[] { "---SELECT---", "LOW", "MODERATE", "HIGH" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

    dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    dynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
       });


    }




private void getData() {


    String bloodglucose = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (bloodglucose.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter bloodglucose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    String dosage =dynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    if (dosage.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter dosage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Calculating insulin dosage...",false,false);

    String url1 = "http://10.1.6.21/getData1.php?bloodglucose="+editText.getText().toString().trim()+"&dosage="+dynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
     },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

     }

    private void showJSON(String response){

    String insulin="";



    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Confignew.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);

         insulin = collegeData.getString(Confignew.KEY_INSULIN);

        Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("value",insulin);

       startActivity(intent1);


       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    getData();

    }

    }
```

NewActivity.java

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Button mBtGoBack;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    TextView tvmessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
    tvmessage.setText("Recommended Insulin Dosage:  "+getIntent().getExtras().getString("value"));

    TextView tvmessage1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_message1);
    tvmessage1.setText("Administered Insulin Dosage:  "+getIntent().getExtras().getString("ids"));
    mBtGoBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_go_back);

    mBtGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
        }
      });

      }
     }
```

Comment: search for how to handle multiple intent or you can pass multiple value from any of one intent

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are re-creating the intent before starting an activity. Each of the intents you are creating only has one value passed through to NewActivity.java. You need to add both values to the same intent rather than re-creating it.

Here is your issue:

```
    Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("ids",myid);

    Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("value",insulin);
```

Rather than instantiating it twice, you should be creating the Intent only once and then adding extras to it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

> The two value is passed to another activity

You're only passing one value to the intent in every `startActivity` call, not two. That's why one is null and the other is not.

Here

```
   Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
   intent1.putExtra("value",insulin);
   startActivity(intent1);
```

And here

```
    Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("ids",myid);
    startActivity(intent1);
```

Just because you name it `intent1` doesn't mean the data is shared.

You need to place **both** extras in the intent.
How about making a helper method, so you don't forget?

```
private void startNewActivity(String recommended, String administered) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("value",recommended);
    i.putExtra("ids", administered);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then use this to get both correct values.

```
startNewActivity("23", "10");
```

---

And by the way, this button event is never actually ran.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String carbohydrate = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
        String dailydose = editText4.getText().toString().trim();
        int cc = Integer.parseInt(carbohydrate);
        int dd = Integer.parseInt(dailydose);
        int goc = 450 / dd;
        int ab = cc / goc;
        myid = Integer.toString(ab);

       // Replace this code with the method
       /*
        Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("ids",myid);
        startActivity(intent1);
      */


    }
});
```

This one is... It overwrites the previous one.

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And does this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the "value" is in getData() method. Wont it return null as they are in different functions?

Comment: You can't reference a variable that is out of scope, sure. You need to pass both variables at the **same time**. That is all my answer is saying.

Answer (score 0):

One `Intent` can open a single `Activity`. What you are trying to do is sending value from two different `Intent`s which you are re-creating inside `onClicks`.

You have to provide `onClick` using any one method. You have first set `clickListener` on `Button` using `Anonymous` Class and implemented the `OnClickListener` at the same time.

Remove `onClickListener` from the button, the part below

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String carbohydrate = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
        String dailydose = editText4.getText().toString().trim();
        int cc = Integer.parseInt(carbohydrate);
        int dd = Integer.parseInt(dailydose);
        int goc = 450 / dd;
        int ab = cc / goc;
        myid = Integer.toString(ab);
        Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("ids",myid);
        startActivity(intent1);


    }
});
```

Keep your overrdien `onClick` as it is.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getData();
}
```

And now edit your `getData()` method to add the removed code

```
private void getData() {
    String bloodglucose = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (bloodglucose.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter bloodglucose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    String dosage =dynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    if (dosage.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter dosage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Calculating insulin dosage...",false,false);

    String url1 = "http://10.1.6.21/getData1.php?bloodglucose="+editText.getText().toString().trim()+"&dosage="+dynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

And finally `showJSON`

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String insulin="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Confignew.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);

        //The code from button's onClickListener
        String carbohydrate = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
        String dailydose = editText4.getText().toString().trim();
        int cc = Integer.parseInt(carbohydrate);
        int dd = Integer.parseInt(dailydose);
        int goc = 450 / dd;
        int ab = cc / goc;
        myid = Integer.toString(ab);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("ids",myid);
        //startActivity(intent1); Put second value too before starting activity


        insulin = collegeData.getString(Confignew.KEY_INSULIN);

        intent1.putExtra("value",insulin);

       startActivity(intent1);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    `enter code here`}
}
```

Comment: The declaring of carbohydrate and dailydose as string in showJSON() throws NullPointerException. It is because it is enabled on button click only.

Comment: You must have problem with your `EditText`s. Make sure they are initialized. On which line the exception occur?

Answer (score -1):

@Rasiga  could you please let me know why 2 OnCickListener is set like

```
`button.setOnClickListener(this)`
```

and

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListner){.....}
```

You are setting 2 onCLickListener for same View

Comment: sorry it was a mistake

Comment: Why downvoted? First the use of 2 onClickListener doesn't make any sense.You should have used just single

Comment: This is a comment, and doesn't address the solution to the problem @Aditi

Comment: @cricket_007 i was just trying to know why 2 listeners are mentioned. You cannot solve a problem if you don't define whether the need for getData is required or just the use of first OnClickListener is sufficient.

Comment: Understood, however you've asked a question, thus not an answer. That's all I'm pointing out